# How do I call a UDF on a Spark DataFrame using JAVA?

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

Similar question as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33829479/spark-sql-how-to-call-udf-from-dataframe-operation-using-java), but don't have enough points to comment there.

According to the latest Spark [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#udf-registration-moved-to-sqlcontextudf-java--scala) an `udf` can be used in two different ways, one with SQL and another with a DataFrame. I found multiple examples of how to use an `udf` with sql, but have not been able to find any on how to use a `udf` directly on a DataFrame.

The solution provided by the o.p. on the question linked above uses `__callUDF()__` which is `_deprecated_` and will be removed in Spark 2.0 according to the Spark Java API documentation. There, it says:

> "since it's redundant with udf()"

so this means I should be able to use `__udf()__` to cal a my `udf`, but I can't figure out how to do that. I have not stumbled on anything that spells out the syntax for Java-Spark programs. What am I missing?

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.api.java.UDF1;
.
.    
UDF1 mode = new UDF1<String[], String>() {
    public String call(final String[] types) throws Exception {
        return types[0];
    }
};

sqlContext.udf().register("mode", mode, DataTypes.StringType);
df.???????? how do I call my udf (mode) on a given column of my DataFrame df?
```

Comment: It is not. Check carefully signatures :) Some example code? UDF + data? Some formatting?

Comment: Added code to clarify what I'm asking. As for the complaining part, I have a nagging feeling that I'm not doing it right. It should not take hours to figure out how to do things in Java-Spark. I think I'm missing something, some book(s), some documentation somewhere, some source of knowledge that will make the clues I get from my IDE sufficient to do things without having to google for hours. Everything I find is Scala and it's not clear at all to me how to do the same things in Java.

Comment: Well, technically speaking Scala classes are valid Java classes. It means these can be used directly in Java. Problem is that Scala is much richer language than Java. It means that many things cannot be easily done without unwrapping all the Scala magic.

Comment: so you're telling me that I do need to move to Scala.. it does seem that this would be a better investment of time than keep trying to shoehorn Spark into Java code. Thank you.

Comment: Not necessarily but it can be easier for you than dealing with Scala internals.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

**Spark >= 2.3**

Scala-style `udf` can be invoked directly:

```
import static org.apache.spark.sql.functions.*;
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.UserDefinedFunction;

UserDefinedFunction mode = udf(
  (Seq<String> ss) -> ss.headOption(), DataTypes.StringType
);

df.select(mode.apply(col("vs"))).show();
```

**Spark < 2.3**

Even if we assume that your UDF is useful and cannot be replaced by a simple `getItem` call it has incorrect signature. Array columns are exposed using Scala `WrappedArray` not plain Java Arrays so you have to adjust the signature:

```
UDF1 mode = new UDF1<Seq<String>, String>() {
  public String call(final Seq<String> types) throws Exception {
    return types.headOption();
  }
};
```

If UDF is already registered:

```
sqlContext.udf().register("mode", mode, DataTypes.StringType);
```

you can simply use [`callUDF`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#callUDF%28java.lang.String,%20org.apache.spark.sql.Column...%29) (which is a new function introduced in 1.5) to call it by name:

```
df.select(callUDF("mode", col("vs"))).show();
```

You can also use it in `selectExprs`:

```
df.selectExpr("mode(vs)").show();
```

Comment: First, thank you. The udf is simplified a little, the one I would end up writing will return a single String that is a function of the String array in the column (row by row, no aggregation). This seemed like a perfect case for one of those functions in the spark.sql.functions suite, but what I need (most frequent item in string array) is not there, hence me trying to develop my own udf().

Comment: I successfully used this solution to split the Spark ML "probability" vector column into multiple columns using Java code. Hopefully, this will help someone find the solution faster than I did.

Comment: In Spark >= 2.3, how do you pass multiple columns to the UDF defined in the answer?