# WrappedArray of WrapedArray to java array

Tags: java, apache-spark, cassandra, apache-spark-dataset

I have a column of type set and I use `collect_set()` of spark Dataset API which returns a wrapped array of wrapped array. I want a single array from all values of the nested wrapped arrays. How can I do that?

Eg. Cassandra table:

```
Col1  
{1,2,3}
{1,5}
```

I'm using Spark Dataset API.
`row.get(0)` returns a wrapped array of wrapped array.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Consider you have `Dataset<Row> ds` which has `value` column.

```
+-----------------------+
|value                  |
+-----------------------+
|[WrappedArray(1, 2, 3)]|
+-----------------------+
```

And it has below schema

```
root
 |-- value: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: array (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- element: integer (containsNull = false)
```

**Using UDF**

Define `UDF1` like below.

```
static UDF1<WrappedArray<WrappedArray<Integer>>, List<Integer>> getValue = new UDF1<WrappedArray<WrappedArray<Integer>>, List<Integer>>() {
      public List<Integer> call(WrappedArray<WrappedArray<Integer>> data) throws Exception {
        List<Integer> intList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for(int i=0; i<data.size(); i++){
            intList.addAll(JavaConversions.seqAsJavaList(data.apply(i)));
        }
        return intList;
    }
};
```

Register and call `UDF1` like below

```
import static org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col;
import static org.apache.spark.sql.functions.callUDF;
import scala.collection.JavaConversions;

//register UDF
spark.udf().register("getValue", getValue, DataTypes.createArrayType(DataTypes.IntegerType));

//Call UDF
Dataset<Row> ds1  = ds.select(col("*"), callUDF("getValue", col("value")).as("udf-value"));
ds1.show();
```

**Using explode function**

```
import static org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col;
import static org.apache.spark.sql.functions.explode;

Dataset<Row> ds2 = ds.select(explode(col("value")).as("explode-value"));
ds2.show(false);
```

Comment: yes, that can be done, I tried it other way, I exploded the sets and then aggregated them using collect_set(), so there was only single array. You are telling me to explode the result of collect_set(). In both cases, I have a concern, that is whether there will be a significant performance hit or not? That's why I was opting for flatten. Also can you point me to some tutorials, books, etc for spark+java(and not scala)+dataset api

Comment: I edited my answer to get Array using UDF. Hope this helps.

Comment: got this error, did i miss anything?The method seqAsJavaList(Seq<A>) in the type JavaConversions is not applicable for the arguments (Integer)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a dataframe you can use a udf to flattern a list 
Below is simple example

```
import spark.implicits._

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
//create a dummy data

val df = Seq(
  (1, List(1,2,3)),
  (1, List (5,7,9)),
  (2, List(4,5,6)),
  (2,List(7,8,9))
).toDF("id", "list")

val df1 = df.groupBy("id").agg(collect_set($"list").as("col1"))

df1.show(false)
```

Output for df1:

```
+---+----------------------------------------------+
|id |col1                                          |
+---+----------------------------------------------+
|1  |[WrappedArray(1, 2, 3), WrappedArray(5, 7, 9)]|
|2  |[WrappedArray(7, 8, 9), WrappedArray(4, 5, 6)]|
+---+----------------------------------------------+


val testUDF = udf((list: Seq[Seq[Integer]]) => {list.flatten})


df1.withColumn("newCol", testUDF($"col1")).show(false)
```

Output

```
+---+----------------------------------------------+------------------+
|id |col1                                          |newCol            |
+---+----------------------------------------------+------------------+
|1  |[WrappedArray(1, 2, 3), WrappedArray(5, 7, 9)]|[1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 9]|
|2  |[WrappedArray(7, 8, 9), WrappedArray(4, 5, 6)]|[7, 8, 9, 4, 5, 6]|
+---+----------------------------------------------+------------------+
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: can you please post a java equivalent code for udf . I saw this flatten function on Seq<Seq<Integer>> but could not use it properly.

Comment: I hope this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35348058/how-do-i-call-a-udf-on-a-spark-dataframe-using-java

Comment: Actually i want the implementation for flatten, it is not as simple as list.flatten in Java may be because Scala is richer. Docs for flatten is single line, doesn't make sense to me :(

Comment: you can write a udf and loop through the array and than create a new array that will be flattern.