# scala spark use udf function in spark shell for array manipulation in dataframe column

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark, dataframe, user-defined-functions

scala/spark use udf function in spark shell for array manipulation in dataframe column

`df.printSchema`

```
root
|-- x: timestamp (nullable = true)
|-- date_arr: array (nullable = true)
|    |-- element: timestamp (containsNull = true)
```

sample data:

```
|x                      | date_arr                                                              |  
|---------------------- |---------------------------------------------------------------------- |  
| 2009-10-22 19:00:00.0 | [2009-08-22 19:00:00.0, 2009-09-19 19:00:00.0, 2009-10-24 19:00:00.0] |  
| 2010-10-02 19:00:00.0 | [2010-09-25 19:00:00.0, 2010-10-30 19:00:00.0]                        |
```

in udf.jar, I have this function to get ceiling date in date_arr according to x:

```
class CeilToDate extends UDF {
  def evaluate(arr: Seq[Timestamp], x: Timestamp): Timestamp = {
    arr.filter(_.before(x)).last
  }
}
```

add jar to spark shell: `spark-shell --jars udf.jar`

in spark shell, I have HiveContext as `val hc = new HiveContext(spc)`, and create function: `hc.sql("create temporary function ceil_to_date as 'com.abc.udf.CeilToDate'")`

when I make a query: `hc.sql("select ceil_to_date(date_arr, x) as ceildate from df").show`, expecting to have a dataframe like:

```
|ceildate              |        
|----------------------|  
|2009-09-19 19:00:00.0 |  
|2010-09-25 19:00:00.0 |
```

however, it throws this error:

org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: No handler for Hive udf class com.abc.udf.CeilToDate because: No matching method for class com.abc.udf.CeilToDate with (array, timestamp). Possible choices: *FUNC*(struct<>, timestamp)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35348058/how-do-i-call-a-udf-on-a-spark-dataframe-using-java

Answer (score 1):

Why are you going through all the complexity of creating a *udf jar* and including the jar in *spark-shell*. You can just create one in *spark-shell* and use that in your `dataframe`.

Given you have `dataframe` as

```
scala> df.show(false)
+---------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
|x                    |date_arr                                                             |
+---------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
|2009-10-22 19:00:00.0|[2009-08-22 19:00:00.0, 2009-09-19 19:00:00.0, 2009-10-24 19:00:00.0]|
|2010-10-02 19:00:00.0|[2010-09-25 19:00:00.0, 2010-10-30 19:00:00.0]                       |
+---------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

You can create a `udf` function in *spark-shell* but before that you would need three `imports`

```
scala> import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

scala> import java.sql.Timestamp
import java.sql.Timestamp

scala> import scala.collection._
import scala.collection._
```

Then you can create a udf function

```
scala> def ceil_to_date = udf((arr: mutable.WrappedArray[Timestamp], x: Timestamp) => arr.filter(_.before(x)).last)
ceil_to_date: org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.UserDefinedFunction
```

Your desired output `dataframe` can be acheived through different methods but simply you can use `select` as

```
scala> df.select(ceil_to_date(col("date_arr"), col("x")).as("ceildate")).show(false)
+---------------------+
|ceildate             |
+---------------------+
|2009-09-19 19:00:00.0|
|2010-09-25 19:00:00.0|
+---------------------+
```

I hope the answer is helpful

Comment: I tried to define udf in the spark shell directly. No error before this step: df.select(ceil_to_date($"date_arr", $"x")). This step gave me this error: ERROR 2017-09-10 13:59:00,844 org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSetManager: Task 0 in stage 12.0 failed 4 times; aborting job
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 12.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 12.0 (TID 439): java.lang.ClassNotFoundException. The full error message see here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/9r2g0yqd90lfg1q/err.txt

Comment: I have updated my last step . :) instead of $ i have used col. for $ you would need to do import sqlContext.implicits._

Comment: I understand $ and col(). The issue is not due to this. I tried and still got the same error message.

Comment: the message is that the udf function is not identified. whats the spark version you are using? and can you make sure if the schema of the table is exactly the same as you posted in question before you call udf function?

Comment: Apache Spark 1.6.2.3 in DSE 5.0.5. I am sure the schema is as df.printSchema