# Convert Array to DenseVector in Spark DataFrame using Java

Tags: java, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

I am running Spark 2.3. I want to convert the column `features` in the following DataFrame from `ArrayType` to a `DenseVector`. I am using Spark in Java.

```
+---+--------------------+
| id|            features|
+---+--------------------+
|  0|[4.191401, -1.793...|
| 10|[-0.5674514, -1.3...|
| 20|[0.735613, -0.026...|
| 30|[-0.030161237, 0....|
| 40|[-0.038345724, -0...|
+---+--------------------+

root
 |-- id: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- features: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: float (containsNull = false)
```

I have written the following `UDF` but it doesn't seem to be working:

```
private static UDF1 toVector = new UDF1<Float[], Vector>() {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public Vector call(Float[] t1) throws Exception {

        double[] DoubleArray = new double[t1.length];
        for (int i = 0 ; i < t1.length; i++)
        {
            DoubleArray[i] = (double) t1[i];
        }   
    Vector vector = (org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector) Vectors.dense(DoubleArray);
    return vector;
    }
}
```

I wish to extract the following features as a vector so that I can perform clustering on it.

I am also registering the UDF and then proceeding on to call it as follows:

```
spark.udf().register("toVector", (UserDefinedAggregateFunction) toVector);
df3 = df3.withColumn("featuresnew", callUDF("toVector", df3.col("feautres")));
df3.show();
```

On running this snippet I am facing the following error:

> ReadProcessData$1 cannot be cast to org.apache.spark.sql.expressions. UserDefinedAggregateFunction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lies in how you are registering the `udf` in Spark. You should not use `UserDefinedAggregateFunction` which is not an `udf` but an `udaf` used for aggregations. Instead what you should do is:

```
spark.udf().register("toVector", toVector, new VectorUDT());
```

Then to use the registered function, use:

```
df3.withColumn("featuresnew", callUDF("toVector",df3.col("feautres")));
```

The `udf` itself should be slightly adjusted as follows:

```
UDF1 toVector = new UDF1<Seq<Float>, Vector>(){

  public Vector call(Seq<Float> t1) throws Exception {

    List<Float> L = scala.collection.JavaConversions.seqAsJavaList(t1);
    double[] DoubleArray = new double[t1.length()]; 
    for (int i = 0 ; i < L.size(); i++) { 
      DoubleArray[i]=L.get(i); 
    } 
    return Vectors.dense(DoubleArray); 
  } 
};
```

---

Note that in **Spark 2.3+** you can create a scala-style `udf` that can be invoked directly. From this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35350706/7579547):

```
UserDefinedFunction toVector = udf(
  (Seq<Float> array) -> /* udf code or method to call */, new VectorUDT()
);

df3.withColumn("featuresnew", toVector.apply(col("feautres")));
```

Comment: @BdEngineer: For machine learning in Spark, Vectors (`DenseVector`, `SparseVector`) are used for input instead of arrays. There could be other use cases as well.