# remove all the special characters from a csv file using spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

how to remove all the special characters from a csv file from a spark dataframe using java spark
For example: Below is the csv file content with spaces and special characters

```
"UNITED STATES CELLULAR CORP. - OKLAHOMA",WIRELESS,"US Cellular"
```

o/p I needed

```
UNITEDSTATESCELLULARCORPOKLAHOMA|WIRELESS|US Cellular( in lower case)
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: code improvements

Answer (score 0):

You should use [String.replaceAll](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) method (and regex) to replace every character that is not alapha numeric to empty string.
Use this as udf and apply to all columns in the dataframe.

The java code should look like

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Column;
import static org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf;
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.UserDefinedFunction;
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.DataTypes;

import java.util.Arrays;

UserDefinedFunction cleanUDF = udf(
  (String strVal) -> strVal.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9]", ""), DataTypes.StringType
);

Column newColsLst[] = Arrays.stream(df.columns())
    .map(c -> cleanUDF.apply(new Column(c)).alias(c) )
    .toArray(Column[]::new);

Dataset<Row> new_df = df.select(newColsLst);
```

Reference: [How do I call a UDF on a Spark DataFrame using JAVA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35348058/how-do-i-call-a-udf-on-a-spark-dataframe-using-java)

Comment: @pragadeeshwaranvenkatachalam I have added a java code. Sorry I couldn't test it, it may not work ex