# Apache Spark 2.3.0 - How to merge two array<string> into one array<string>

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-java

I tried and googled but was not able to find the solution.
Merging two `array<string>` into one `array<string>` is possible and easy in 2.4.x versions but could not find a way to do it in 2.3.0 version.

Input -

```
[[one, two, three], [four, five, six]]
```

Expected Output -

```
[ one, two, three, four, five, six]
```

Can anyone explain how this can be achieved in Spark using Java?

Answer (score 0):

As new arrays functions were introduced in Spark 2.4, you have to go to [user-defined function](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-functions-udf-scalar.html) (udf).

User-defined functions in java are java objects with an `apply` method that can be used as a built-in function in dataframe transformation. To create such object, you first create an `UDFx` object, where `x` is the number of arguments of your udf.

Then you create your udf from this `UDFx` object, either by registering it with method `sparkSession.sqlContext().register().udf()` (only method available before Spark 2.3) or by creating it with function `udf` (for Spark 2.3 and greater) as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35350706/6807769).

And finally you use it with function `callUdf` or directly using `apply`. So complete code for Spark 2.3 and above is as follow:

```java
import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row;
import org.apache.spark.sql.api.java.UDF1;
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.UserDefinedFunction;
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.DataTypes;
import scala.collection.Seq;

import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import static org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col;
import static org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf;
import static scala.collection.JavaConverters.asScalaBuffer;
import static scala.collection.JavaConverters.seqAsJavaList;


public class Flattener {

  public static Dataset<Row> flattenArray(Dataset<Row> input, String columnName) {
    // define what your user-defined function do
    UDF1<Seq<Seq<String>>, Seq<String>> flattenArray = new UDF1<Seq<Seq<String>>, Seq<String>>() {
      @Override
      public Seq<String> call(Seq<Seq<String>> s) {
        return asScalaBuffer(
          seqAsJavaList(s)
            .stream()
            .flatMap(x -> seqAsJavaList(x).stream())
            .collect(Collectors.toList())
        ).toSeq();
      }
    };

    // convert it to user-defined function
    UserDefinedFunction flatten_array = udf(
      flattenArray, 
      DataTypes.createArrayType(DataTypes.StringType) // output type of your UDF
    );

    // apply your user-defined function
    return input.withColumn(columnName, flatten_array.apply(col(columnName)));
  }
}
```

> Note: when working with sequence on java UDF, you need to use Scala `Seq` instead of java `List` as sequence input. To convert from one to another, look at [`JavaConverters`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.x/index.html#scala.collection.JavaConverters$) scala class methods.

You can then call your `flattenArray` method on your dataframe:

```java
Flattener.flattenArray(dataframe, "name_of_column_you_want_to_flatten");
```